# How to include "param" name in JSON @Body Retrofit Android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I need to call a service from Android.
I tested the service with Postman and it works, but the services receives one parameter named "parametros", is a ArrayList in JSON format, it looks like this
[image]

the right format is

```
{
    "parametros": [
        {
            "Nombre": "@@IdCliente",
            "Valor": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

it's with the param name "parametros" included.
In postman it works fine.

But in Android I have:

```
interface APIService {

    @POST("/getMovimientos")
    fun getMovimientos(@Body parametros: List<APIParameter>): Call<BalanceVO>
}
```

and my request looks like this:

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://xxxxxxx/getMovimientos
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 38
D/OkHttp: [{"Nombre":"@@IdCliente","Valor":"1"}]
    --> END POST (38-byte body)
```

The parameter

`[{"Nombre":"@@IdCliente","Valor":"1"}]`

should be

`"parametros":[{"Nombre":"@@IdCliente","Valor":"1"}]`

How can I configure my app to put this param name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct your body as an object of a data class as below

```
data class APIRequestPayload (
    val parametros: List<APIParameter>
)

data class APIParameter (
    val Nombre: String,
    val Valor: String
)
```

then use it as the below on service

```
fun getMovimientos(@Body parametros: APIRequestPayload): Call<BalanceVO>
```

To use it, pass the body as an obj,

```
service.getSaldo(parametros=APIRequestPayload(parametros=List<APIParameter>)).enqueue()
```

Still naming the val `Nombre` is not conventional, you may annotate with `@SerializedName("Nombre") val nombre` to stick with variable naming conventions if using GSON

Comment: Thank you very much !!!, it solves my problem, I just need encapsulate my `APIParameter` in a parent class `APIRequestPayload `.

Answer (score 1):

Create a data class like this and assign list to it and pass it as body

```kotlin
data class ParametrosBody(val parametros: List<APIParameter>)
```

```kotlin
val parametros = ...//your list
val body = ParametrosBody(parametros)
```

```kotlin
interface APIService {

    @POST("/getMovimientos")
    fun getSaldo(@Body parametros: ParametrosBody): Call<BalanceVO>
}
```